# Special join with limit and search options

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

> DB structure:
>   ID | MasterID (selfref. on ID) | Productcode
>   
>   DB data:
>   
>   1 | 0 | One
>   2 | 1 | Two
>   3 | 1 | Three
>   4 | 0 | Five
>   5 | 0 | Six

I want to select all 'master' products (WHERE MasterID=0) with their childrens (WHERE MasterID=ID of Master).
I need an LIMIT on the master products, but their childrens must always be selected, too.
It should be possible to search e.g. for Productcode.

I tried something like (Subquery) without success:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM products
        WHERE MasterID = 0
        LIMIT 100
    ) p1
    JOIN products p2 on p1.ID = p2.MasterID
) tmp
WHERE xyz = xyz
```

////////////////////////////
EDIT:
What i need to have:

> With where Productcode='One' (or LIMIT 1):
>   1 | 0 | One
>   2 | 1 | Two
>   3 | 1 | Three (because the other two does have the search value as MasterID
>
> With where Productcode='Three'
>   1 | 0 | One
>   2 | 1 | Two
>   3 | 1 | Three (because Three does have a Master and the Master does have another 'kind' (Two))

////////////////////////////

Does anyone have an idea?

Best regards,
frgtv10

Comment: You use a sub query to determine the table you use?

Comment: Is there a better way? Union does not allow a reference on query or alias one.

Comment: So, you don't want the 4 and 5 to be shown.

Comment: without a search, i want to show 100 products (+ kindproducts, then it could be over 100). when searching for 'three' i want to show all related other products ('two' and 'one') because of the master and kind procuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
LEFT JOIN products p2 on p1.ID = p2.MasterID
```

And you don't need 3 levels:

```
SELECT p1.*
     , p2.*
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM products
    WHERE MasterID = 0
    LIMIT 100
) p1
    LEFT JOIN products p2
        ON p1.ID = p2.MasterID
        AND p2.Productcode = xyz
```

The above will return all master products related to children with Productcode=xyz and all other up to 100 (unrelated) master products.

---

What you describe with you sample is far more complex:

```
  ( SELECT ID
         , masterID
         , Productcode
    FROM products p
    WHERE masterID = 0
      AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM products p2
        WHERE p.ID = p2.MasterID
          AND p2.Productcode = 'two'
      )
    LIMIT 100
  )
UNION
  ( SELECT ch.ID
         , ch.masterID
         , ch.Productcode
    FROM
      ( SELECT ID
        FROM products p
        WHERE masterID = 0
          AND EXISTS
          ( SELECT *
            FROM products p2
            WHERE p.ID = p2.MasterID
              AND p2.Productcode = 'two'
          )
        LIMIT 100
      ) AS m
    JOIN products ch
        ON m.ID = ch.MasterID
  )
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not working too. I only get the 'master' products. Any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you updated your question, adding a simple table of results you want to be shown, it would help others to understand better what you seek.

Comment: thanks ypercube for your help!
it's looking good, but i receive following structure:

ID | Pcode | ID2 | Pcode2
1 | One | 2 | Two
1 | One | 3 | Three.
In my comment above i show u what it need to be.

Comment: thanks for the complex query above! When searching for a kind product e.g. Two, i dont get any result. When there is no search, i only get master products who have existing kind products.